# Asana Projects API Not Returning All Projects

Tags: asana, asana-api

We are experiencing an issue where we are requesting all projects from a workspace, but, only 29 projects are being returned.  Many are missing.   This is the code we are using: https://gist.github.com/dzoba/921ec35073d6329aecadc08ceacb445e

This is the list of projects we are returned:

https://gist.github.com/dzoba/4a57a61849c2bdf3c610aa6d02082482

This is an image of some of the projects for this Workspace.  (I've removed all last names). If you compare you can see many of the ones that end in " - Marketing" are not returned by the API.

[image]

How can I get all projects from a workspace, and why aren't all being returned?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because the account that created the API access token was not a team member of the teams which contained these projects.  We made that account and admin and a team member, which fixed the issues.